# Why does calling future.exception() in a done callback change the traceback

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I noticed that error messages in [Carthage](https://github.com/hadron/carthage) were sometimes getting truncated.  That code is quite complex, so I worked on reproducing things in simpler form and found:

- If I attach a done callback to a coroutine that calls the `result` method
- I also await the coroutine elsewhere
- the coroutine raises a exception

Then the traceback that eventually gets printed  only includes  the await call but not the portion of the traceback in the coroutine.  However in the done callback never calls `result` I get the full traceback.

```py
import asyncio

async def my_traceback_gets_mangled():
    def bar():
        raise TypeError('I wish I had a traceback that let me find this bogus raise')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    bar()

def done_cb(fut):
    try: fut.result()
    except: pass
    
async def main():
    fut = asyncio.ensure_future(my_traceback_gets_mangled())
    fut.add_done_callback(done_cb)
    await fut

asyncio.run(main())
```

If I run that, I see:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/foo.py", line 18, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/tmp/foo.py", line 16, in main
    await fut
TypeError: I wish I had a traceback that let me find this bogus raise
```

But if I remove the call to `fut.result`, then the traceback includes the call to bar and actually shows where the `TypeError` gets raised.
Interestingly in pypy (rather than cpython), I get the behavior I expect, namely that I get the full traceback.